# What happens with the if statement when it's true?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I started with HackerRank and I'm a bloody beginner.

So I've a question to this code:

```
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.trim().split('\n').map(string => {
        return string.trim();
    });

    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}
/*
 * Create the function factorial here
 */
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    }
    return n;
}

function main() {
    const n = +(readLine());

    console.log(factorial(n));
}
```

I broke it down to something like this:

Let's depend n = 4;

```
4 === 1 ? // NO!
THEN:
4 * factorial(4-1) // n = 3;

3 === 1? // NO!
THEN:
3 * factorial(3-1) // n = 2;

2 === 1? // NO!
THEN:
2 * factorial(2-1) // n = 1;

1 === 1? // YES!
return 1;
```

What happens NOW? What happen with return 1 and what happend with all the other "loops"?! And why does it loop over and over, even when there is no loop?

Please try to explain as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your code looks like (slight modification from above)

```
4 === 1 ? // NO!
THEN:
4 * factorial(2) // n = 3;

3 === 1? // NO!
THEN:
3 * factorial(2) // n = 2;

2 === 1? // NO!
THEN:
2 * factorial(1) // n = 1;

1 === 1? // YES!
return 1;
```

When `return 1` is executed, `1` is returned to caller of the function `factorial(1)`.

Now this function `2 * factorial(1)` is waiting for the value of `factorial(1)`, so it can execute `2 * factorial(1)`. Now it does `2 * 1` and gives you `2`. This value is returned to the caller of `factorial(2)` function.

Same process `3 * factorial(2) // n = 2;` is waiting for `factorial(2)`. Javascript solved this in the previous iteration and now it is able to do `3 * 2` = 6. This `6` is returned to the caller of `factorial(3)`.

And finally `4 * factorial(3)` does `4 * 6` = 24

And your answer is `24`

Better explanation about how it all works behind the scenes

https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I didn't get it :(

Comment: @minternational sorry if my explanation wasn't clear

You can read it a lot better here

https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea

Comment: https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea

Comment: I don't think it's a lack of quality in your explanation :)